# ms access sql - select case when in select subquery

Tags: sql, ms-access, subquery

I have a table with multiple rows per person and need to get one row per person and the max scores, if a flag is yes, and other things (this is just a snippet of the columns for this example)

Data table

| person | qtime | flag | score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Bob | quarter1 |  | 4 |
| Bob | quarter2 | no | 6 |
| Bob | quarter4 | no | 3 |
| Alice | quarter1 | no | 4 |
| Alice | quarter2 | yes | 7 |
| Alice | quarter3 | yes | 9 |

```
select
    person,
    max(score) as maxScore,
    case 
       when person in (select person from data where flag = 'yes') 
          then 1 
          else 0 
    end as flagYes
from
    data
group by 
    person
```

This would work fine in Microsoft SQL server but in MS Access SQL I get

> Syntax error (missing operator in query expression)

I can use aliases in the subquery if that makes things feel like it wouldn't cause problems but they don't make the query get rid of this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MS Access doesn't support `case` expressions.  You can use `IIF()` instead:

```
select d.person, max(d.score) as maxScore,
       iif(d.person in (select d2.person from data as d2 where d2.flag = 'yes'), 1, 0) as flagYes
from data as d
group by person
```